# Modal javascript php open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

how could I open the contents of an external php file within this modal?

```
// Demo modal
    function openplaylist()
    {
        $.modal({
            content: 'modal content'+
                      '</ul>',
            title: 'Playlist',
            width: 300,
            scrolling: false,
            actions: {
                'Fechar' : {
                    color: 'red',
                    click: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                },

            },
            buttons: {
                'Fechar': {
                    classes:    'huge blue-gradient glossy full-width',
                    click:      function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                }
            },
            buttonsLowPadding: true
        });
    };
```

Did i open the file "manage-playlist.php" within this modal.
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just download your page first and then open modal:

```
function openplaylist()
{
    $.get('manage-playlist.php', function(data) {
        $.modal({
            content: data,
            title: 'Playlist',
            width: 300,
            scrolling: false,
            actions: {
                'Fechar' : {
                    color: 'red',
                    click: function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                }

            },
            buttons: {
                'Fechar': {
                    classes:    'huge blue-gradient glossy full-width',
                    click:      function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
                }
            },
            buttonsLowPadding: true
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: does not work :/ .. my Javascript does not work After putting " $.get('manage-playlist.php', function(data) {
        $.modal({
            content: data, "

Comment: Fixed some syntax a bit, please update. Can you show me a page where you're testing this script if it's still does not work?